# Access enqueued_at from Sidekiq worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

Is there a way to get the Sidekick job object from a worker in order to access its `enqueued_at` attribute? I wanna create records using the `enqueued_at` timestamp in the `created_at`/`updated_at` fields for a Sidekiq queue that's been paused for a long time (and in case I pause it again).

Answer (score 4):

You can only access job metadata from middleware.  If your worker needs data, it must be passed as arguments to the worker.